# VS2012 C# - vshost32 has stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vshost32

I have a windows form application which is basically a PDF viewer. I used the Adobe PDF Viewer COM component for this project.

The program works but I'm having an issue when I click the close button on the top right of the form after I open a pdf file. When I click the close﻿ button, VS does not exit the 'run'-mode and I have to manually click the 'stop' button on VS. And when I press the stop button, a window pops saying "vshost32 has stopped working".

However, this does not happen when I run the application and close it without opening a pdf file.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: `VS does not exit the 'run'-mode and I have to manually click the 'stop' button ` This means that Process is still running. I mean you will be having some other ForeGround threads running.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My project has no more than one thread as far as I know. I just used the adobe pdf viewer component and dragged that to my winform. In addition to that, I only have two buttons, one to open a pdf file, and one to exit the application.

Answer (score 0):

You may have manually release the COM object by using Marshal. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The vshost32.exe is related to designer-simulation tasks in window forms, so try creating a new project then improt your classes from the old one.

Comment: Hi, I tried recreating the project. But it is still giving me the 'vshost32 has stopped working' window